# DoubleAnimation Height not returning to original value after trigger event is not being triggered anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, storyboard

I'm trying to put some styling in my listbox, when the listbox is created it has the size for one item and when the mouse is over, it should increase its height to fit 5 items, so far so good, but since it becomes annoying when the user pass the mouse over it to go to another field, it gets annoying seeing it growing and returning to its original size.

So I decided to try Storyboards with DoubleAnimation for this ListBox. I reached this:

```
    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:.25">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="20" To="85" Duration="0:0:0"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Ok, that works. Perfect, I'm almost feeling pro already. But when I went for the tests, I got problems. When the mouse is not over anymore, the listbox won't go backto its original size. So I decided to do the opposite and try to use `Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"`
with the `From` and `To` values switched. The ListBox wouldn't move.

So I tried an answer I saw in StackOverflow saying about `DataTemplate.Triggers` but got the same result.

I don't know what else to try since my lackof knowledge in WPF gets in the way everytime.

What is a good alternative for this? Thanks in advance and opinons are always welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an additional returning `Storyboard` in `Trigger.ExitActions`

```
<Trigger.ExitActions>
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:.25">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                             From="85" To="20" Duration="0:0:0"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</Trigger.ExitActions>
```

Without that the `Storyboard` holds the value by default. See [FillBehavior Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx).

---

Alternatively you could set `FillBehavior="Stop"` and set the new `Height` value if `IsMouseOver` is true like you do for `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility`.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="20" To="85"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.5" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="85" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. But only one thing, when the Storyboard is triggered, my background event won't get triggered too. Is there any way to fix that? :X Thanks in advance, thanks a lot.

Comment: What background event do you mean?

Comment: MouseLeave="ListBox_MouseLeave" In this event I'm just making the selected item show when the ListBox has the length to show only one item.

Comment: And why this event should fire if mouse is over ListBox and triggers IsMouseOver? I've tried and it fires if mouse leaves ListBox. Expected behavior.

Comment: At least here, if the doubleanimation has been activated, the code behind event doesn't trigger, is there a way to trigger an event from the storyboard ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, I can take from now on, thanks for caring about my problem and helping me a lot. Thanks again.